# SVN Externals and tags/versions

Tags: svn

I'm working in a project that uses svn.externals. I read this can create problems when creating tags and branching but the articles I read are a few years old. Is this still a problem or has it been solved in later versions of Subversion?

The problems described is that the tag points always to the latest checkin among other things.

/jne

Comment: They may be a few years old, but since branching & tagging hasn't changed much if at all over the years, they're still relevant (technical details, anyway).

Comment: An important detail: do you use svn:externals to a fixed revision or to HEAD?